Is a line driver necessary for distributing a 24.576 MHz clock signal to multiple digial MEMS microphones at long distance?
I’m sending a 24.576 MHz clock signal from my MCU to a series of ICS-52000 microphones via a 50 cm FFC cable. The clock signal originates from a single MCU pin and is distributed to 16 microphones. To ensure a stable and reliable clock signal for all microphones, I’m considering using the SN74LVC1G125DCKT  line driver.
Would using a line driver like the SN74LVC1G125DCKT  be a good solution in this case? Are there any alternative approaches or considerations I should keep in mind when distributing a high-frequency clock signal over this length and to multiple devices?


Is it really AUP12 or is there a missing number? AUP125 and 126 do exist. Can you link to a data sheet?

Fixed that. It's SN74LVC1G125DCKT

I'm not familiar with the details of MEMs microphones.  But what is their requirement for jitter or phase variation between mics?

It depends on your bus topology. And strength of MCU output pin.
So in general to avoid these problems, you could drive the MCU output to a few line drivers and then have a star network that would be otherwise impossible.
But if this AUP125 is good depends on what you require. Your cabling has some capacitance and the mic input is capacitive with few pF. You need to know approximately what kind of signal shape you need and if AUP125 can drive the load with sharp enough signal shape you need. The AUP125 is not very strong compared to many other buffer gates, but AUP125 may be strong enough for your needs.
